# React jsx not rendering audio source file from fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I have a express server serving an array of audio files. My react component "fetch" is making a fetch request and performing some logic to get a random file from that endpoint.  I then am trying to pass the random file as a src for an jsx audio tag but not sure if its reading it as a string or a mp3. also done really know if the file is even working correctly. Please help.

```
import React , {useState} from "react"
import { Audio } from './audio'


export function Fetch() {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState('');
    let audio = new Audio;

    function getData(){
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/files')
     .then((res) =>res.json()
    )
    .then((files) => {
     let num  =  Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length);
     audio.src = files[num];    
     console.log(files[num]) 
      setFiles(files[num])


    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
    return ( 
        
        <div>

            
            <button onClick ={getData}>click</button>
            
              { files !== '' && <audio src={audio.src} controls autoPlay/>
                      }
        </div>
    )


}
`
```

Comment: does this work if you hardcode the value into your audio tag

Comment: Yeah it works but i need it to be from the backend

Comment: sure, what exactly is the current error? can you be more specific about what is and isn't working? make sure to `console.log` the values before your return statement you are unsure about to check

Comment: Im fetching data (mp3 files from a dir on my cpu ) using express im putting them on a server and in react im fetching them and im trying to set one random one as state and use state as a src for an audio file. Ive gotton as far as to log a random one to the console but cant figure it out passed that.

Comment: you're explaining what you want to do, but you're not explaining what the current issue is

Comment: When i try to set the src of the audio tag to the value of state it doesnt work

Comment: are you getting an error in the browser console? is the value of `src` correct?

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a helpful description of what the problem is. I assume it doesn't work already otherwise you wouldn't be here asking for help :p

Comment: oh I can spot one issue. change `<audio src={audio.src} controls autoPlay/>` to `<audio src={files} controls autoPlay/>

Comment: no error in the browser im logging the value of state to the browser and that is printing the names of the files. The value of src is referencing state. The audio tag in the browser wont let me press play.

Comment: what happens if you put `audio.src = files` right above your return statement

Comment: Didnt work.. same issue. However the audio tag now reacts when i push the button but no file being played

Comment: Same thing.. didnt work.

Comment: maybe `files[num]` isn't a valid path?

Comment: Im able to log it to the console. When i click the onclick it logs random files from the JSON so i know its going through